# Finding and sorting cousins in a binary tree using BFS

Tags: python, sorting, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I am trying to identify the names of all the cousins of particular family member in a binary tree.
The input data is a list of lists in this format:

```
family = 
[
['George', 75, ['Bob', 'Vicky']],
['Bob', 48, ['Tom', 'Sophie']],
['Vicky', 42, ['Karen']], 
['Tom', 23, []], 
['Sophie', 21, []], 
['Karen', 19, []]
]
```

Where each list represents `[person, age, [child1, child2]]`
Each person can have at most 2 children. The information of a parent is always given before that of the children and no two names are the same. The cousins should be output youngest first. Where cousins are of the same age, they should be ordered in alphabetic order.

Example function and output:

`>>> cousins(person, family)`

`>>> ['cousin1', 'cousin2',...]`

My attempt so far:

```
import math
import operator

def BFS(tree,level=["brown"]):
    """breadth-first search on tree."""
    bfs_list = []
    if len(level) > 0:
        bfs_list += level
        sub_level = []
        for vertex in level:
            if vertex not in tree:
                continue
            sub_level += tree[vertex]
        bfs_list += BFS(tree,sub_level)
    return bfs_list

def siblings(g,h,lst):
    """determine if two nodes are sibling."""
    return any([(g in lst[k]) and (h in lst[k]) for k in lst])

def parent_child(a,b,lst):
    """determine if two nodes have a parent-child relationship."""
    return any([(a in lst[b]), (b in lst[a])])

def cousins(p, people):
    """determine cousins of a family member."""
    famdict = {lst[0]:lst[2] for lst in people}
    agelst = sorted([(j[0], j[1]) for j in people], key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0))
    names = BFS(famdict, [people[0][0]])
    i = names.index(p)+1
    s = math.floor(math.log2(i))
    e = 1 + s
    pcuz = names[2**s-1:(2**e)-1]
    f = [n for n in pcuz if all([(not parent_child(p,n,famdict)), (not siblings(p,n,famdict))])]
    return [q[0] for q in agelst if q[0] in f]
```

sample input and output:

```
>>> cousins("Tom", family)

>>> ['Karen']
```

My implementation seems to work so far but I am sometimes getting timeout due to runtime error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to find the path of family members down to the target member, and then work back up the returned result:

```
family = [['George', 75, ['Bob', 'Vicky']], ['Bob', 48, ['Tom', 'Sophie']], ['Vicky', 42, ['Karen']], ['Tom', 23, []], ['Sophie', 21, []], ['Karen', 19, []]]
def paths(d, s, t, c = []):
   if s == t:
      yield c
   else:
      for i in d[s]['children']:
        yield from paths(d, i, t, c+[s])

def cousins(person, family):
  f = {a:{'age':b, 'children':c} for a, b, c in family}
  r = max([i for a in f for i in paths(f, a, person)], key=len)
  if len(r) < 2:
     return []
  *_, g, p = r
  return sorted([i for b in f[g]['children'] for i in f[b]['children'] if b != p], key=lambda x:(f[x]['age'], x))


print(cousins('Tom', family))
print(cousins('Bob', family))
```

Output:

```
['Karen']
[]
```

Comment: I tried your code but I get a ValueError whenever I enter someone who doesn't have any cousins ("Bob"). I would like an empty list to be returned whenever a person has no cousins. Could you modify your code to include that. Thanks.

Comment: @Clifton Thank you for your comment, please see my recent edit.

Comment: It seems to be working for the tree given here. Is this a general algorithm for trees of this kind?

Comment: @Clifton Yes, I wrote this algorithm to work on trees with the format of `[name, age, [children]]`. Please let me know if there are more specific input cases that need to be handled, however.

Comment: It's giving me the expected results with my tests but in HackerRank it's only passing one test case and telling me that the answers are wrong. I'm not sure what is off here.

Comment: @Clifton Please post the troublesome inputs with the desired output.

Comment: That's the hard part because the actual inputs and outputs are all hidden. The only thing I know is the general form of the input stated above. My code was passing more test cases but I expect yours to pass all of them being that it's more well thought out.

Comment: @Clifton Hmm. I suggest manually tweaking the current input (adding new family members, etc) and testing it on the solution and checking the results.

Comment: I will try that. Also, does this code only return first cousins?

Comment: @Clifton Yes, only first cousins.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the tree so that 'john' and 'kate' are cousins.

```
family = [
["brown", 88, ["chad", "stacy"]],
["chad", 50, ["kirk", "margon"]], 
["stacy", 48, ["simone","sam"]], 
["simone", 18, ["kate"]], 
["kirk", 25, ["john"]], 
["margon", 20, []], 
["john", 10,[]],
["kate",4,[]], 
["sam",3,[]]
]

def paths(d, s, t, c = []):
   if s == t:
      yield c
   else:
      for i in d[s]['children']:
        yield from paths(d, i, t, c+[s])

def cousins(person, family):
  f = {a:{'age':b, 'children':c} for a, b, c in family}
  r = max([i for a in f for i in paths(f, a, person)], key=len)
  if len(r) < 2:
     return []
  *_, g, p = r
  return sorted([i for b in f[g]['children'] for i in f[b]['children'] if b != p], key=lambda x:(f[x]['age'], x))


print(cousins('kate', family))
```

However, this code returns [].

Comment: `[]` should indeed be the correct output for that example because Kate's ancestry is `['brown', 'stacy', 'simone']`. Therefore, starting at `stacy`, Kate's uncle is `"sam"`, however, `"sam"` is pointing to an empty list (`sam` has no children). Thus, Kate has no cousins.